# cnc z axis motor huming when homing

Tags: cnc

I am using GRBL and UGS with an arduino uno and its CNC shield.

Once I send the $H command, the z motor is moving a little bit and then it goes crazy. I mean it's starts to hum and doesn't move anymore. After that, the machine is in ALARM state. ALARM:8.

Once I send $X command, the machine goes back to idle. So i am now able to use my cnc machine again. But why am I not able to set it to home position ?

[image]

**config:**

$0 = 10    (Step pulse time, microseconds)

$1 = 25    (Step idle delay, milliseconds)

$2 = 0    (Step pulse invert, mask)

$3 = 0    (Step direction invert, mask)

$4 = 0    (Invert step enable pin, boolean)

$5 = 0    (Invert limit pins, boolean)

$6 = 0    (Invert probe pin, boolean)

$10 = 1    (Status report options, mask)

$11 = 0.010    (Junction deviation, millimeters)

$12 = 0.002    (Arc tolerance, millimeters)

$13 = 0    (Report in inches, boolean)

$20 = 0    (Soft limits enable, boolean)

$21 = 1    (Hard limits enable, boolean)

$22 = 1    (Homing cycle enable, boolean)

$23 = 0    (Homing direction invert, mask)

$24 = 25.000    (Homing locate feed rate, mm/min)

$25 = 500.000    (Homing search seek rate, mm/min)

$26 = 250    (Homing switch debounce delay, milliseconds)

$27 = 1.000    (Homing switch pull-off distance, millimeters)

$30 = 1000    (Maximum spindle speed, RPM)

$31 = 0    (Minimum spindle speed, RPM)

$32 = 0    (Laser-mode enable, boolean)

$100 = 250.000    (X-axis travel resolution, step/mm)

$101 = 250.000    (Y-axis travel resolution, step/mm)

$102 = 250.000    (Z-axis travel resolution, step/mm)

$110 = 500.000    (X-axis maximum rate, mm/min)

$111 = 500.000    (Y-axis maximum rate, mm/min)

$112 = 500.000    (Z-axis maximum rate, mm/min)

$120 = 10.000    (X-axis acceleration, mm/sec^2)

$121 = 10.000    (Y-axis acceleration, mm/sec^2)

$122 = 10.000    (Z-axis acceleration, mm/sec^2)

$130 = 200.000    (X-axis maximum travel, millimeters)

$131 = 200.000    (Y-axis maximum travel, millimeters)

$132 = 200.000    (Z-axis maximum travel, millimeters)